# Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key While using a program that uses petsc and libconfig

Tags: 20.04

I am getting the following error message while running my program. I have no `.Xauthority` file present in my home directory. I am trying to run this program on my local machine. And the program runs fine in HPC clusters.

```
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key[nirmal:278600] *** Process received signal ***
[nirmal:278600] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[nirmal:278600] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[nirmal:278600] Failing at address: 0x440000e8
[nirmal:278600] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x14420)[0x7f7057722420]
[nirmal:278600] [ 1] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.40(PMPI_Comm_set_errhandler+0x47)[0x7f70579dbfc7]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the message "Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key" is unrelated to the segmentation fault. To get rid of the message, try setting the HWLOC_COMPONENTS environment variable like this (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/75813452/21988144)

```
export HWLOC_COMPONENTS="-gl"
```